# I want an alert message. Enter your name the click on button like add. If the textplace is empty its shows an error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, snackbar, react-native-paper

```
        <Button onClick={handleClick} 
                variant="contained" size="medium"
                style={{backgroundColor:"#4CB04F", color:"white" }} >
            Accept
        </Button>
      
        <Snackbar
         anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "right",
        }}
          open={open} autoHideDuration={3000} onClose={handleClose}
        >
          <Alert
            onClose={handleClose}
            severity="success"
            
          >
            The file has been Uploaded Successfully
          </Alert>
          
        </Snackbar>
```

Comment: I assume `on Close` is supposed to be `onclose`?

Comment: actually this is not my code i just want to know that if i cann't enter the text and direct click on button then its shows an alert like an error message.

Comment: We can't know what you mean if you don't provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Snackbar component from React Native Paper. If you look at the docs [here](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/snackbar.html), you will notice the Snackbar already is an alert, and you should not be adding another Alert inside it.

```
  <Snackbar
    visible={visible}
    onDismiss={onDismissSnackBar}
    action={{
      label: 'Undo',
      onPress: () => {
        // Do something
      },
    }}>
    The file has been Uploaded Successfully
  </Snackbar>
```

In that same example you will find a Button component:

```
<Button onPress={onToggleSnackBar}>{visible ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</Button>
```

This button has an `onToggleSnackBar` function. This is where you should check if the text area is empty or not.